# rolling month formula ignoring 0's?

Tags: excel, average, formula

How would one go about about writing a formula for a rolling 6 month average, but ignoring cells that return "0"? I have data spread across 12 columns with one cell for each month of the year, however, some cells are filled with values > 1 and other have 0.

Below formula does a good job if there are no 0's, but ruins the calculation if there are any.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(E2;0;COUNT(E2:P2)-IF(COUNT(E2:P2)>3;3;COUNT(E2:P2));1;IF(COUNT(E2:P2)>3;3;COUNT(E2:P2))))
```

Suggestions anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to average the most recent six months that have non-zero or positive values, looking back far enough to see six positive values?  Or do you want to average the most recent six months, just ignoring the zero values such that if only 4 months out of the last six were non-zero,  only those four would be averaged.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I need the average of the last 6 months that are not 0s, which means for example if I have non zero data for 8 months (Jan to Aug), and zero data from Sep to Dec, then the formula should calculate the average from Mar to Aug.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the DAVERAGE function.

In a2 to a7 I placed:

```
aField
10
11
9
0
10
```

In c1 to c2, I placed:

```
aField
>0
```

Now for the DAVERAGE. I used: `=DAVERAGE(A2:A7,1,C1:C2)`. This instructs Excel to look at a2:a7 as a database, to look in the first field, and to only average the ones where aField > 0.

Comment: I'd also search the web for DAVERAGE Excel. Here's a decent example: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/daverage.php . Hope that helps.

Comment: I cant really work with this... My data is spread across columns, not rows as per your example, but even if I adjust the formula it ends up averaging every value in the range thats not zero. This doesnt help since I need only the last 6 months of nonzero data. Also, the syntax for Daverage requires me to specify the "afield" value twice (once for the data range and once for the filter condition), which doesnt go with my table design. thank you though, but I would prefer a standalone formula without any helpers.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an **array-entered** formula:

```
=AVERAGE(N(OFFSET(E2,0,-COLUMN(E2)+LARGE((E2:P2>0)*COLUMN(E2:P2),{1,2,3,4,5,6}))))
```

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
`ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula.

The formula looks for the 6 "largest" columns (highest column number) that have a value greater than zero; then uses those column numbers in the `OFFSET` function to return the values contained in those cells; and then averages them.

For reasons not clear, the `N` function allows the `AVERAGE` function to see all the values.  Without it, it only returns the last value returned by `OFFSET`

Comment: thanks, but is there any non-array solution? I would need to do this for 300+ records on multiple sheets which would greatly impact the speed...

Comment: I don't know of a formula that would accomplish that.  What have you found when you did an internet search?

Comment: @Armitage2k You could write a UDF (User Defined Function) in VBA which might be faster.  Or, you could use a VBA Macro.  For the amount of data you need to process, a Macro could be faster, but you would need to define your problem.  I suggest you write something, and, if you run into problems, post the code here with questions.